# html structure confusion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 different pages with same html structure and in one jquery based slider is working while in other one it's not.

How is this possible? Please check my html structure and tell me what is wrong?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
     <link href="css/stylecss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <a href="http://dev7studios.com" id="dev7link" title="Go to dev7studios">dev7studios</a>
        <div id="content"
        <div id="main">
        <div id="posts">
            <div class="post">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="uploads/gallery/nemo_crtac/toystory.jpg"/>
                <img src="uploads/gallery/nemo_crtac/up.jpg"/>
                <img src="uploads/gallery/nemo_crtac/walle.jpg"/>
                <img src="uploads/gallery/nemo_crtac/nemo.jpg"/>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
             <div id="pages"></div>
            <div id="countries"></div>
    </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="class/ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="class/faq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="class/style.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="class/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="class/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
</script>
```

[EXAMPLE WORKING](http://lookaroundyou.net/demo.html)
[EXAMPLE NOT WORKING](http://lookaroundyou.net) (loading gif forever)

Answer (score 3):

Using Chrome, on the page that's not working I get this error in the console:

**Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://lookaroundyou.net/ from frame with URL http://player.vimeo.com/video/16163053?color=ffffff. Domains, protocols and ports must match.**

Even if that's not specific to the slider function, errors can halt execution of the remaining scripts. Try it without loading the video player and see if that clears things up, then troubleshoot the player.